# How to get ID field from recordset?

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, recordset

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click()
Dim RST As New ADODB.Recordset
With RST
     Open "SELECT * FROM tblStandardFolders2009 WHERE StandardFoldersID = 0", fnCNN, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
        .AddNew
            !Description = Me!txtAddGeneric
            !MakeNewContract = False
        .Update
        fnStandardFolders2009ID (RSD!StandardFoldersID)
        .Close
    End With
Set RST = Nothing
```

This code adds a record to one of my tables. I need to get the primary key after it's added so that I can use it in another method. RSD!StandardFoldersID is "empty" according to Access. Any ideas?

EDIT: Using "SELECT @@Identity" afterwards does work but it's not reliable and I know there are better ways.

Comment: Why not simply create a stored procedure in sql server to insert the data and return the value of identity? You really should start thinking that way anyway to separate the data and presentation layers.

Comment: I agree but I inherited this Access application from another developer and a lot of the code relies on opening recordsets in this way. Any ideas as to getting the ID field using my current method?

Comment: If you want to fix this you have to do it in small chunks right? This seems like a great time to start fixing things. Otherwise use SCOPE_IDENTITY

Comment: How would I go about using SCOPE_IDENTITY?

Comment: How did you use @@IDENTITY? Same thing, only scope_identity is safer.

Comment: Doesn't work, just returns a null value

Comment: Well then you would either have to stick with @@IDENTITY or fix it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem and thought I would give an answer for anyone in the future who views this.
The connection object being used to open the Recordset had 'adUseServer' as the cursor location. After changing the cursor location to 'adUseClient' I was able to see the ID of newly created records.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 Private Sub btnAdd_Click()
    Dim RST As New ADODB.Recordset
    With RST
         Open "SELECT * FROM tblStandardFolders2009 WHERE StandardFoldersID = 0", fnCNN, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
            .AddNew
                !Description = Me!txtAddGeneric
                !MakeNewContract = False                    
            .Update
            .Bookmark = .LastModified
            fnStandardFolders2009ID (CLng(RST!StandardFoldersID))
            .Close
        End With
    Set RST = Nothing
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It's not a data type problem. It literally just sees the ID field as empty, all the other fields have values except the ID field, yet when I check SQL Server it has been added and has a valid ID.

Comment: In your code, you were using RSD as recordset variable not RST. have you tried to change it

Comment: Ah yes I did change that but it didn't help, still empty